# Chomsky Hierarchy and LL(*) parsers

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, theory, chomsky-hierarchy

I want to parse a programming language. I read a lot about formal languages and the Chomsky hierarchy and ANTLR. But I could not find information on how to relate the languages ANTLR v3 as an LL(*) recursive descent parser accepts to the chomsky hierarchy.

How do the Chomsky types mix with LL(*)? Any information (online, books, papers) are greatly appreciated.

Edit: How do syntactic / semantic predicates and backtracking of ANTLR map into this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Chomsky Hierarchy is basically:

1. Regular languages
2. Context-Free Grammars
3. Context-Sensitive Grammars
4. Recursively Enumerable (Turing-Complete) Grammars

LL Grammars (and parsers) are a subset of context-free grammars. They are used because regular languages are too weak for programming purposes and because a general context-free parser is O(n^3) which is too slow for parsing a program.
Indeed, augmenting a parser with helper functions does make it stronger.
[The Wikipedia entry on LL parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) explains some of this.[The Dragon Book](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) is considered a leading textbook on compilers, and may explain further.

Answer (score 4):

LL(*) is a subset of context-free languages. However, a different question is what antlr can parse, given predicates and backtracking, which extend its abilities.

Note that if we talk about LL(*), that means ANTLR v3, not 2.